# access headers with ngResource

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, ngresource

I have a Api in which retrieves a custom header: X-Total-Count : "total of items", I'm using angular with `ngResource`.

My factory look like this:

```
app.factory("shopFactory", function ($resource) {
    return {
        User: $resource("http://localhost:58495/users/api/User/?id=:id", { id: "@id" }),
        Category: $resource("http://localhost:58495/category/:id", { id: "@id" }),
        Product: $resource("http://localhost:58495/products/?from=:from&to=:to", { from: "@from", to: "@to" })
    };
});
```

And when I call it:

```
var productServer = shopFactory.Product.query({ from: 0, to: 10 }).$promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.product = response;
        console.log(response);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(error);
    });
```

How can I access my custom header through ngResource, I can access it but with $http, I want to do it with the $resource way, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query` action method can be called with three arguments:

```
Resource.query([parameters], [success], [error])
```

The success callback is called with `(value (Object|Array), responseHeaders (Function), status (number), statusText (string))` arguments, where the value is the populated resource instance or collection object. The error callback is called with `(httpResponse)` argument.

```
var productServer = shopFactory.Product.query(
    { from: 0, to: 10 },
    function success (value, headers, status, statusText) {
        $scope.product = value;
        console.log(value);
        console.log(headers());
    }, 
    function error (error) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $resource Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

---

> whats the difference between using `$promise.then` and the success function,

The function in the `.then` method exposes only the `value` of the final response. While the success callback exposes four arguments: `value (Object|Array), responseHeaders (Function), status (number), statusText (string)`.

The `$promise` can be passed as an argument to other functions and its `.then` method can be invoked multiple times.

Another very important difference is that the `.then` method creates a new promise from values returned.

> ## Chaining promises
>
> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.
>
> It is possible to create chains of any length and since **a promise can be resolved with another promise** (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.
>
> [— AngularJS $q Service API Reference (Chaining Promises)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)

Comment: Thanks, it worked flawlessly. I have only a question, whats the difference between using $promise.then and the success function, Thanks you very much.